# launchPermissionRequest does not prompt after two times denial

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I was using the code from [here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
private fun FeatureThatRequiresCameraPermission() {

    // Camera permission state
    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

    if (cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) {
        Text("Camera permission Granted")
    } else {
        Column {
            val textToShow = if (cameraPermissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) {
                // If the user has denied the permission but the rationale can be shown,
                // then gently explain why the app requires this permission
                "The camera is important for this app. Please grant the permission."
            } else {
                // If it's the first time the user lands on this feature, or the user
                // doesn't want to be asked again for this permission, explain that the
                // permission is required
                "Camera permission required for this feature to be available. " +
                    "Please grant the permission"
            }
            Text(textToShow)
            Button(onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
                Text("Request permission")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected. However, if the user denies two times then next time `launchPermissionRequest()` does nothing. Is there any way to make it unlimited or know the status that `launchPermissionRequest()` is disabled.

Comment: you can show snacbar that shows permission for daniel's detail and that contains one button and click on that to navigate to settings.

Comment: @HanifShaikh but when do we show the button? what would be the condition unless you want to store the number of clicks in preference or something

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the users Android version, this is intended behavior.

> At the same time, your app should respect the user's decision to deny a permission. Starting in Android 11 (API level 30), if the user taps Deny for a specific permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if your app requests that permission again. The user's action implies "don't ask again." On previous versions, users saw the system permissions dialog each time your app requested a permission, unless they had previously selected a "don't ask again" checkbox or option.

Meaning, no you cannot make it ask for an unlimited time. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial) about handling permission denial for more information.

However you can detect this scenario in your code by checking the `shouldShowRationale` variable in the `locationPermissionsState` and then explain to the user why they need to grand this permission and send them to the settings. This is from the [accompanist example](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/permissions/RequestLocationPermissionsSample.kt):

```
val allPermissionsRevoked = locationPermissionsState.permissions.size ==
                locationPermissionsState.revokedPermissions.size

        val textToShow = if (!allPermissionsRevoked) {
            // If not all the permissions are revoked, it's because the user accepted the COARSE
            // location permission, but not the FINE one.
            "Yay! Thanks for letting me access your approximate location. " +
                "But you know what would be great? If you allow me to know where you " +
                "exactly are. Thank you!"
        } else if (locationPermissionsState.shouldShowRationale) {
            // Both location permissions have been denied
            "Getting your exact location is important for this app. " +
                "Please grant us fine location. Thank you :D"
        } else {
            // First time the user sees this feature or the user doesn't want to be asked again
            "This feature requires location permission"
        }
```